# mod_rewrite ignores VirtualHost (Apache / Wamp)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp, virtualhost

I am trying to rewrite everything to index.php with this mod_rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I put this code at the bottom of my httpd.conf file and it works fine if I do not use any VirtualHosts. However, the mod_rewrite code gets totally ignored if I add a VirtualHost for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/MyDomain/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I am hosting several web pages on different domains from the same server, so I am using VirtualHosts to make one root directory for each site. How come mod_rewrite does not cooperate with these VirtualHosts?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inherit your rule in your VirtualHosts, you need to add these lines inside each of them:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
```